# Java curve program

Tags: java, graphics

I am new to java and I have to make a program that include 2 parts:

1. I have a polynom that shows me how should I print a curve.I will obtain the polynom by receiving some 2d coordonates, and making some mathematical calc. So I, will get a polynom that looks like this: `(x^2 + 2x + 1, x + 9)`
2. I print the curve, and after when i click the image, my curve modifies after the new coordonates i click.

The professor didn't gaved us any materials that we could use for the graphic part. I've searched on the internet but I didn't found any reliable information for part2.That's way I am asking you what packages should I use. I want to say thanks to all that will answer.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0):

[JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart) is arguably the best library for working with charts and data, and it's API is well documented .
It may be a bit overkill for your application, but its a suggestion.

Edit: [An example of how to plot functions](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=61448)